# Summation of Series with Anonymous functions in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I'm a bit confused how I can find the summation of the following which I need for a gui.
Given n,x,y,a,b

[image: summation]

I know that there exists the summation function with symbolic function with symsum()
but I would like to avoid using the symbolic toolbox. 
x and y are also given as

> [x, y] = meshgrid(-2:sp:2);

This is what I have so far in terms of x and y for the summation part, I'm not sure how to go about doing this. Thanks

```
@ (x,y)(2./N).*(sin((N.*pi.*x)./a)).*(sinh((N.*pi.*y)/a))./(sinh((N.*pi.*b)./a));
```

Comment: It looks like `x` and `y` are in [-2, 2]. What is the range of `a` and `b`. Are they real? Nonnegative? Positive? Also, what is the origin of this formula – that might be helpful

Comment: Store that function handle with a name like `f1`, so - `f1 = @ (x,y)(2./..` and then use `f1(x,y)` to get the 2D output which would be `w`?